# NuGet 3.3+: contentFiles not added to project

Tags: nuget

After reading everything I could find about the new `contentFiles` element of NuGet 3.3+, I still can't manage to make it work in my package. I've got a package that targets both `net46` and `uap10.0`, and the selection of the right DLLs for the project type and platform work as expected. But I would also like to add two files to the project on package installation, one CSV file for all projects and platforms, and one code file for either C# or VB.Net (with `buildAction="Compile"`). Here's the abridged version of my latest .nuspec file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata minClientVersion="3.3.0">
    ...
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="any\any\ErrorCodes.csv" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="false" />
      <files include="cs\any\Errors.cs.pp" buildAction="Compile" />
      <files include="vb\any\Errors.vb" buildAction="Compile" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="contentFiles\any\any\ErrorCodes.csv" target="contentFiles\any\any\" />
    <file src="contentFiles\cs\any\Errors.cs.pp" target="contentFiles\cs\any\" />
    <file src="contentFiles\vb\any\Errors.vb" target="contentFiles\vb\any\" />
    ...
  </files>
</package>
```

The package is created without errors, and it does contain the three files in the contentFiles folder with the specified directory structure.

But when I install the package - I tried it with with both an Universal App (C# and VB) and a .NET 4.6 console app I modified to use a `project.json` file - the reference to the DLL is added, but the content files are neither added to the project structure, nor copied into the project directory.

I am thankful for any input!

Answer (score 8):

OK, I found that the contentFiles are actually working, but not in the way I expected it to. A short description for everybody who couldn't find his/her contentFiles:

- NuGet 3.3+ contentFiles are *not* added to the project structure. You will not see them in Visual Studio.
- Instead, the files are extracted into a folder in the project's *obj* folder, and referenced (if the file is code). You will even see the classes or methods in your contentFiles code files available in IntelliSense. In my case, the `Errors` class was accessible, although it wasn't visible anywhere in the project.
- The path of the extracted files has the following schema: \obj\<Debug or Release>\NuGet\<some GUID>\<NuGet package name>\<version>\

I'm not sure if I like this new mechanism. Code coming from some invisible source I cannot see in Visual Studio (a library shipped via NuGet is visible in References, any code it brings via contentFiles is not) may pose problems at times. I actually discovered that the contentFiles mechanism is working when I got an ambiguity error in Visual Studio because the "invisible" Errors.cs from the NuGet package collided with the "visible" Errors.cs I had added to the project manually.

Comment: i don't like this new mechanism - it adds a lot more stress to the process - hard to see what is going on

Comment: i'm confused, i'm trying to follow your nuspec file, and while i do see contentFiles in the packages directory, nothing goes to the obj folder. Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try to compile the project? I think the files are copied to the obj folder during compilation.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue.  I did figure out that .NET Core projects use [`PackageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) by default. Not sure how to fix / work around.