# My Nuget Package is not merging in static content

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, nuget

I created a Nuget Package for VS 2015, .Net Core MVC, with framework target of 4.61.

My nuspec looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyThing</id>
    <version>0.9.5</version>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    <owners>Us</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>This should merge in this content, but doesn't</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2016</copyright>
    <tags>Core MVC</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" version= "1.0.0"/>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" version= "1.0.0"/>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration" version= "1.0.0"/>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel" version= "1.0.0"/>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" version= "1.0.0"/>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" version= "1.0.0"/>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" version= "1.0.0"/>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" version= "1.0.0"/>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" version= "1.0.0"/>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" version= "1.0.0"/>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions" version= "1.0.0"/>
      <dependency id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader" version= "14.0.0"/>
      <dependency id="xunit" version= "2.1.0"/>
      <dependency id="xunit.runner.console" version= "2.1.0"/>
      <dependency id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version= "2.1.0"/>
      <!--dependency id="dotnet-test-xunit" version= "1.0.0-rc2-build10025"/-->
    </dependencies>
    <contentFiles>
      <!-- Include Assets as Content -->
      <files include="**/wwwroot/**/*.*" buildAction="EmbeddedResource" />
      <files include="**/Controllers/*.*" copyToOutput="true" />
      <files include="**/Model/*.*" buildAction="None" />
      <files include="**/Views/*.*" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" />
      <files include="**/Views/**/*.*" buildAction="EmbeddedResource" copyToOutput="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

The variety of include parameters are to demonstrate that none of them work. The files are not copied to the project they are added to, but they exist in the nuget package cache.

Comment: Is your target project managed by a project.json file? That's the only project type that supports NuGet contentFiles.

Comment: Yes, it is a VS 2015 Update 3 Core site with a project.json.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same issue when I use the same .nuspec file content. I have checked the package by unzip the nupkg file, all the files listed in `<contentFiles>` tag are pack into the package successful. But the files are not installed into the project where the package installed.

Even though the files are not displayed in project structure, the content files will working as expected. For example, if you content a .cs file in `<contentsFiles>`, after installing the package, you could use the class and members in this .cs file.

Please refer to:
[NuGet 3.3+: contentFiles not added to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985232/nuget-3-3-contentfiles-not-added-to-project)